# Creating Mandatory User Filters with multiple element IDs

Tags: gooddata

## Mandatory User Filters

I am working on a tool to allow customers to apply Mandatory User Filters. When attributes are loaded like "Year" or "Age", each can have hundreds of elements with the subsequent ids. In the POST request to create a filter (documented here: https://developer.gooddata.com/article/lets-get-started-with-mandatory-user-filters), looks like this:

```
{
    "userFilter": {
        "content": {
            "expression": "[/gdc/md/{project-id}/obj/{object-id}]=[/gdc/md/{project-id}/obj/{object-id}/elements?id={element-id}]"
        },
        "meta": {
            "category": "userFilter",
            "title": "My User Filter Name"
        }
    }
}
```

In the "expression" property, it notes how one ID could be set. What I want is to have multiple ids associated with the object-id set with the post. For example, if I user wanted to add a filter to all of the elements in "Year" (there are 150) in the demo project, it seems odd to make 150 post requests.

Is there a better way?

**UPDATE**

Tomas thank you for your help.

I am not having trouble assigning multiple userfilters to a user. I can easily apply a singular filter to a user with the method outlined in the documentation. However, this overwrites the userfilter field. What is the syntax for this?

Here is my demo POST data:

```
{ "userFilters": 
  { "items": [ 
    { "user": "/gdc/account/profile/decd0b2e3077cf9c47f8cfbc32f6460e", 
      "userFilters":["/gdc/md/a1nc4jfa14wey1bnfs1vh9dljaf8ejuq/obj/808728","/gdc/md/a1nc4jfa14wey1bnfs1vh9dljaf8ejuq/obj/808729","/gdc/md/a1nc4jfa14wey1bnfs1vh9dljaf8ejuq/obj/808728"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This receives a BAD REQUEST.

Comment: Please note that Mandatory User Filters have been renamed to Data Permissions (https://help.gooddata.com/doc/en/project-and-user-administration/managing-project-data-and-data-access/data-permissions).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "have multiple ids associated with the object-id" exactly, but I'll try to tell you all I know about it. :-)

If you indeed made multiple POST requests, created multiple userFilters and set them all for one user, the user wouldn't see anything at all. That's because the system combines separate userFilters using logical AND, and a Year cannot be 2013 and 2014 at the same time. So for the rest of my answer, I'll assume that you want OR instead.

There are several ways to do this. As you may have guessed by now, you can use AND/OR explicitly, using an expression like this:

```
[/…/obj/{object-id}]=[/…/obj/{object-id}/elements?id={element-id}] OR [/…/obj/{object-id}]=[/…/obj/{object-id}/elements?id={element-id}]
```

This can often be further simplified to:

```
[/…/obj/{object-id}] IN ( [/…/obj/{object-id}/elements?id={element-id}], [/…/obj/{object-id}/elements?id={element-id}], … )
```

If the attribute is a date (year, month, …) attribute, you could, in theory, also specify ranges using BETWEEN instead of listing all elements:

```
[/…/obj/{object-id}] BETWEEN [/…/obj/{object-id}/elements?id={element-id}] AND [/…/obj/{object-id}/elements?id={element-id}]
```

It seems, though, that this only works in metrics MAQL and is not allowed in the implementation of user filters. I have no idea why.

Also, for your own attribute like Age, you can't do that since user-defined numeric attributes aren't supported. You could, in theory, add a fact that holds the numeric value, and construct a BETWEEN filter based on that fact. It seems that this is not allowed in the implementation of user filters either. :-(

Hope this helps.

Comment: First solution worked great, can you check out the update? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the POST data that you say you're sending? I see this in the logs:

    JSON Parser returned error: malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 112 (before "("[/gdc/md/a1nc4jfa1...")